# Как посчитать сколько по времени работает программа C#?

Tags: c#, время

вывести снизу время

```
using System;

public static class CF3051520

{
    
    public static ulong SquareDistance((int x, int y) a, (int x, int y) b)
    {
        long x = a.x - b.x;
        ulong square = (ulong)(x * x);
        long y = a.y - b.y;
        square += (ulong)(y * y);
        return square;
    }
    public static (ulong a, ulong b, ulong c) SortSide(ulong a, ulong b, ulong c)
    {
        while (a < b || a < c)
        {
            (a, b, c) = (b, c, a);
        }
        if (a == c)
        {
            (a, b, c) = (c, a, b);
        }
        return (a, b, c);
    }
    public static (int x, int y) Parse(string x, string y)
    {
        return (int.Parse(x), int.Parse(y));
    }

    public static ((int x, int y) a, (int x, int y) b, (int x, int y) c) Parse(ReadOnlySpan<string> nums)
    {
        return (Parse(nums[0], nums[1]), Parse(nums[2], nums[3]), Parse(nums[4], nums[5]));
    }

    public static bool TriangleEquals(string line)
    {
        var nums = line.Split();
        var firstNums = Parse(nums);
        var secondNums = Parse(nums[6..]);
        (ulong a, ulong b, ulong c) first = (SquareDistance(firstNums.a, firstNums.b), SquareDistance(firstNums.b, firstNums.c), SquareDistance(firstNums.c, firstNums.a));
        (ulong a, ulong b, ulong c) second = (SquareDistance(secondNums.a, secondNums.b), SquareDistance(secondNums.b, secondNums.c), SquareDistance(secondNums.c, secondNums.a));
        first = SortSide(first.a, first.b, first.c);
        second = SortSide(second.a, second.b, second.c);
        return first == second;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(TriangleEquals(Console.ReadLine()) ? "YES" : "NO");        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/277177/

Comment: Можно через 'Stopwatch' в принципе: https://clck.ru/32omFk

Comment: а какое отношение к вопросу имеет приведённый код?